# gradient descent for linear regression in python code

Tags: python, gradient-descent

```
def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    inner = np.power(((X * theta.T) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))

def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters):
    temp = np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
    params = int(theta.ravel().shape[1]) #flattens
    cost = np.zeros(iters)

    for i in range(iters):
        err = (X * theta.T) - y

        for j in range(params):
            term = np.multiply(err, X[:,j])
            temp[0, j] = theta[0, j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))

        theta = temp
        cost[i] = computeCost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, cost
```

Here is the code for linear regression cost function and gradient descent that I've found on a tutorial, but I am not quite sure how it works.

First I get how the `computeCost` code works since it's just (1/2M) where M is number of data.

For `gradientDescent` code, I just don't understand how it works in general. I know the formula for updating the theta is something like

`theta = theta - (learningRate) * derivative of J(cost function)`. But I am not sure where `alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term`) this comes from on the line updating `temp[0,j]`.

Please help me to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break this down for you. So in your gradientDescent function, you are taking in the predictor variables(`X`), target variable(`y`), 
the weight matrix(`theta`) and two more parameters(`alpha`, `iters`) which are the training parameters. The function's job is to figure out how much should 
each column in the predictor variables(X) set should be multiplied by before adding to get the predicted values of target variable(`y`). 
In the first line of the function you are initiating a weight matrix called `temp` to zeros. This basically is the starting point of the 
final weight matrix(`theta`) that the function will output in the end. The `params` variable is basically the number of weights or number of predictor variables. 
This line makes more sense in the context of neural networks where you create abstraction of features.

In linear regression, the weight matrix will mostly be a one dimensional array. In a typical feed forward neural networks we take in a lets say 5 features, 
convert it to maybe 4 or 6 or n number of features by using a weight matrix and so on. In linear regression we simply distill all the input 
features into one output feature. So `theta` will essentially be equivalent to a row vector(which is evident by the line `temp[0,j]=...`) and `params` will be the number of features. We `cost` array just stores
that array at each iteration. Now on to the two loops. In the line `err = (X * theta.T) - y` under the first `for` loop, we are calculating the prediction 
error for each training example. The shape of the `err` variable be `number of examples,1`. In the second for loop we are training the model, 
that is we are gradually updating our `term` matrix. We run the second for loop `iters`
number of times. In Neural network context, we generally call it epochs. It is basically the number of times you want to train the model.

Now the line `term = np.multiply(err, X[:,j])`: here we are calculating the individual adjustment that should be made to each weight in the `temp` matrix. 
We define the cost as (y_predicted-y_actual)**2/number_of_training_points, where y_predicted = X_1*w_1 + X_2*w_2 + X_3*w_3 +... If we differentiate this cost vwith respect to 
a particular weight(say W_i) we get (y_predicted-y_actual)*(X_i)/number_of_training_points where X_i is the column that W_i multiplies with. So the `term =` line 
basically computes that differentiation part. We can multiply the `term` variable with the learning rate and subtract from W_i. 
But as you might notice the `term` variable is an array. But that is taken care of in the next line. 
In the next line we take the average of the `term` (by summing it up and then dividing it by `len(X)`) 
and subtract it from the corresponding weight in the `temp` matrix. Once the weights have been updated and stored and the `temp` matrix, 
we replace the original `theta` by `temp`. We repeat this process `iters` number of times

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So you said "the term = line basically computes that differentiation part" but I still don't get how the differentiation works here. The term multiplies the X values with the error which (X * theta.T) -y, but what does that have to do with differentiation?

Comment: When you differentiate the error with respect to `theta`, you get `X*(X*theta.T-y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you , instead of writing it like `((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))`, write it like `(alpha * (np.sum(term) / len(X)))` ,which you're allowed to do since multiplication and division are comutative (if i remember the term correctly) then you just multiply alpha by the average error, since term is length X anyway.

This means that you substract the learning rate (alpha) times average error which would be something like X[j] * tetha (actual) - y (ideal) , which incidentally is also close enough to the derivative of (X*tetha - y)^2

Comment: Isn't it commutative?

Comment: i knew i had that wrong. Should have checked wiki before i posted